# Need to query distinct combination of two fields, along with a count that distinct combination occurs

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, count, combinations

What I need is a query on a table that would return distinct combinations of columns A and B, along with the count of how many times each combination occurs in the table. This would all be sorted by Column A.

If the table were:

```
A    B  .......
1    1
1    1
1    1
1    2
2    1
2    1
```

The result would be:

```
A    B     count
1    1       3
1    2       1
2    1       2
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: google and learn how `group by` works

Comment: I note that your table has no primary key - which may prove problematic further along

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GROUP BY is your friend here:

```
select a,b,count(*) from test
group by a,b
order by a
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/062b0e/5

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` like this

```
SELECT
    `A`,
    `B`,
    COUNT(*) AS `Count`
FROM
    `table`
GROUP BY
    `A`, `B`
ORDER BY
    `A`
```